# the best way to move the cursor in vim visual block to change the block width to one char width

Tags: vim

the best way to move the cursor in vim visual block  to change the block width to one char width?

For example:

This is my text:

```
ooo1xxxxx2oo
oooxxxxxxxoo
oooxxxxxxxooooooooooo
oooxxxxxxxooooooooooo
ooo4xxxxx3ooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooooo
```

Now in the visual **--block mode--**, my cursor si on '3', and the selected block is:

```
1xxxxx2
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
4xxxxx3
```

I want to change above selected block to

```
1
x
x
x
4
```

now how I quickly move my cursor from 3 to 4 just with less key? (not use the 'F4' or '?4')(the '1','2','3','4'，'x','o' is For convenience of explanation， they may be random characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I can do is this sequence of commands:

```
<Esc>gvoO`<o
```

That is, **Escape** to leave Visual mode, **`gv`** to reselect. This is necessary to have the `<` and `>` marks set properly (they are set only after leaving Visual mode).

**`oO`** to move the cursor to the top right corner of the selection.

**`` `< ``** to shrink the selection to a single column.

**`o`** again to move the cursor to the bottom of the selection.

Consider a custom mapping if you need this often:

```
:xnoremap <Leader>O <Esc>gvoO`<o
```

Comment: Vim golf: ``OmmO`m``. Note that this changes the `m` mark which may not be desired.

Answer (score 1):

when your cursor is on `3`, pressing `O`  (big O) in `visual mode`, will move cursor to `4`

And you might want to know as well, when cursor on `3`, pressing `o` (small o) will move cursor to 1

```
:h v_o
:h v_O
```

Answer (score 1):

After leaving the current selection (with <kbd>Esc</kbd>), the `'<` and `'>` marks will be helpful. Unfortunately, there's no built-in motion that just considers their line / column (and ignores the other coordinate).

What I would do is observe the size of the selection (in the lower right corner, `5x7` in your example), leave the selection with `<Esc>`, go to the beginning `` `< ``, re-enter blockwise visual mode `<C-V>`, and move the previously noted number of lines (`5`), minus 1, down: `4j`.